# Place a block in multiple regions

Tags: blocks

Is there a module which can allow users to place the same block in multiple regions? That way I don't have to make the same View block twice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Multiblock](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock) module makes this possible:

> Drupal's block module is limited by the fact that a block can only
>   have one instance. Each block has a 1:1 relationship with its region,
>   weight, visibility (and other) settings. This means that it is
>   impossible to have blocks in multiple regions or to have blocks that
>   have different settings on different pages. MultiBlock module solves
>   this problem by allowing you to create multiple Block Instances of
>   already existing blocks.

Answer (score 6):

It is unclear if you want to use the same block more than once on the same page or place it in different regions on different pages.  Either way I would recommend you take a look at the [context module](http://drupal.org/project/context).

Using context you can place a block with in different regions on different pages.  Alternatively you can create 2 contexts which apply to the same page/s and place the same block in different regions.

Comment: It should be noted that this doesn't appear to work when putting a block twice within the same region. It appears that Context can only put one copy of a block per region.

Answer (score 3):

The [Panels module](http://drupal.org/project/panels) also makes it easy to use multiple instances of the same block on a page.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a custom module for the site, you can define your own blocks to repeat the content of an existing block. It will then appear twice in the block listing

```
/* -------------------
    custom blocks
----------------- */

/**
* Declare what blocks are provided by this module.
* Implements hook_block_info().
*/
function MYMODULE_block_info(){

    $block['fibble_home'] = array(
        'info' => t('fibble (home)'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
    );
    $block['fibble_members'] = array(
        'info' => t('fibble (members)'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
    );
    return $block;
}

/**
* Define what our block is going to look like.
* Implements hook_block_view().
*/
function MYMODULE_block_view($block_key){
    $block = array();

    // tweets block to appear twice

    if($block_key == 'fibble_home' || $block_key == 'fibble_members'){ 

        //This is the title of the block.
        $block['subject'] = t('Fibble');

        $fblock = module_invoke('MODULE_ORIGINAL_BLOCK', 'block_view', 'ID_ORIGINAL_BLOCK');
        $fcontent = render($fblock['content']);

        $block['content'] = '<!-- content repeated by MYMODULE -->';
        $block['content'] .= $fcontent;

    }

    return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [MultiBlock](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiblock) Module.

Go to Structure->Blocks->Instances. Give a unique instance title and select the block type and save. Then enable the block by assigning it to a region where you want.

Comment: The whole process is explained after enabling Multiblock module.

Comment: @SaayantaAcharyyaChoudhury Then you should have edited the original answer to make it better instead of writing another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bean](http://drupal.org/project/bean) module also now has this functionality.  Not just for custom block entities but also for blocks defined in hook_block. See the dev version and the bean_all submodule.