# Create a footer menu from primary links and should be able to control what should appear

Tags: 7

I have a menu at the top on hover it expands. I want a menu at bottom of page with same links, but i may choose what should appear here. Is there any module available for it. [image]

Comment: There is a similar post on this - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10817/post-the-same-menu-as-two-different-blocks. However, i think your extra need is to be able to disable/enable menu items, differently in the two blocks, correct?

Answer (score 2):

For this functionality, try [Footer Sitemap](https://drupal.org/project/footer_sitemap)

It allows you to choose which menus and/or menu items will be included in the footer sitemap.

You can then customize the template included to manipulate the markup if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You need a region in footer, of course, but I guess that's not a problem. You have 2 viable ways to display a copy of menu (without actually duplicating it's data):

1. [Menu block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module. It's pretty simple - you create a block displaying menu items, and it gives you broad control of what, how, how deep et cetera.
2. Views. You need to expose `{menu_links}` table to views using your own custom module. Or you can search for ready made one, I'm sure there was one in 6.x times, but I can't find it now. With menu links available as views fields, you can do pretty much everything.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your installed Drupal theme supports in terms of regions, you should be able to position your menu at the footer of your pages. When logged in as an admin, go to the admin/structure/block section (append this to your site domain for a direct link). Here you'll be able to choose where to position your menu.

[image: setting up menu to appear at footer]

Other menu systems to consider: http://drupal.org/project/megamenu

Comment: But this solution would move the existing menu into footer, rather than create a static (= not hover-expandable) copy of the main menu, which is what the asker is apparently after. I would recommend OM Maximenu, although I think for footer menu it's a bit of an overkill.

Comment: +1 wow another awesome module, Artur that you mention, http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu Isn't Drupal great! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with [Menu Clone](http://drupal.org/project/menu_clone) module.