# How to include the same block in two regions?

Tags: views, blocks

I created a views block and have included it in the Content region for one of the pages... I would like to call the same block on a different region on the homepage. Is this possible?

Comment: You can find your answer from here : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9677/place-a-block-in-multiple-regions

Comment: Thanks @StoneVo

https://drupal.org/project/multiblock doesn't seem to have a recommended version for drupal 7 :(

Comment: There is a stable release (7.x-1.1); the fact is listed under "Other releases" doesn't mean it it not stable. It is quite the opposite, since there are just two open bug reports, and at least 9,598 sites are using that version.

Comment: Yes, anyway you can try with 7.x-1.1 while waiting for the next release.